# IntelliJ IDEA Please configure the JDK to match the expected one

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I just switched from Android Studio to intelliJ IDEA and I am trying to build my previous Android project. However, I am getting the following error upon on build.

> The newly created daemon process has a different context than expected.
>   Java home is different.
>   Expecting: '/Applications/IntelliJ_IDEA_CE.app/Contents/jdk/Contents/Home' but was: '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home'.
>   Please configure the JDK to match the expected one.

In my project structure's JDK setting, it is set to the IntelliJ's default JDK location but it seems like to be modified by some other configurations.

I have tried various solutions I could found online but still getting no where.

I have added the following option in my global gradle.properties:
`org.gradle.java.home=/Applications/IntelliJ_IDEA_CE.app/Contents/jdk/Contents/Home`

I have also tried deleting ./idea in my project and rerun the application but it is still showing the same error message.

I am not sure if anyone has another solution that worked for this problem. Thanks a lot!

PS. I am running IntelliJ on MAC.

Comment: Do you face the same error without changing  global gradle.properties? Have you checked the issue with new sample project?

Comment: @y.bedrov, Yes, I have already tried start a new project, and it is showing the same error with(out) changing the global gradle.properties.

Comment: See this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/57193266/6897913
Hope this is work for you .

Comment: **MODIFY default Boot JDK** Friendly link:https://stackoverflow.com/a/57193266/6897913