# IntelliJ/Gradle Could not determine java version from '11.0.1'

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle, version

I'm running a Linux Ubuntu 18 OS. Installed jdk in a custom local directory.

Normally, IntelliJ recommends that you `use the default gradle wrapper`. But in my case, I want to be able to change the Gradle Version on the fly whenever it's due for an update.
If you use IntelliJ with Gradle, and you bump into the following error:

```
Could not determine java version from '11.0.1'
```

Comment: I had similar issue with idea 2019.1, java 12.0.1 and gradle 4.6. I solved the problem by upgrading my gradle to 5.2.1.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you use IntelliJ

Checks:

1. Navigate to:

   `File >> Settings >> Build, Execution, Deployment >> Build Tools >> Gradle`.

   Alongside `Gradle JVM:` 
   make sure you select the correct version of Java.
   [image: Gradle JVM]
2. Navigate to:
   Right-Click 'Project Root Directory' & Select `Open Module Settings`. `Project Structure` windows shows-up. Make sure your JDK home path is added to the `Platform Settings >> SDKs : JDK home path`
   [image: Project Structure >> Platform Settings >> SDKs : JDK home path]
3. Still, on the same window `Project Structure`, select correct SDK relevant to your project under

   `Project Settings >> Modules : Module SDK` 
   [image: Module SDK]
4. Fix/Solution:
   Nvavigate to & open: `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` & update the distributionUrl version to the latest version. 
   In my case (at the time of this post), my older version was:

   `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-bin.zip`

   And my latest version is:

   `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-bin.zip`

   As shown below:

   [image: distributionUrl Version Update]
5. In your build.gradle file make sure you set:

   `sourceCompatibility = 11`

Answer (score 11):

If you are using the latest version of intellijIdea.

In my case, 2019.1 -version

**Delete** the directory **idea's jdk**

then **RESTART** idea.

for detail see this pic

[image]

Hope this is working for you !

In chinese:

(If you can't read chinese,you needn't to read this.All you need to know have typed above already)

如果你是用最新版本的intellijidea.由于intellijidea默认安装了11的java。而且就算你输入java -verison,告诉你是java8，在ide里面也配置了java 8 idea还是告诉你这个错误。

只有通过删除idea自己下载java11版本，可以解决这个问题。直接删除应用包下的jdk文件夹，重启idea就可以。如下图。

Comment: Well... it seems unbelievable but this actually worked for me.  I see this issue here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-210875, and it seems that deleting this directory somehow reset's intellij's internal JDK.  Either way, you have my upvote.  Just very strange that this *did* work.

Comment: @BrooksDuBois Thank you for your precious upvote.May be this is a bug about this version of intellj idea .

Comment: Where would you find this folder in Linux installations? Or do you have to remove another file or folder here?

Answer (score 2):

Your gradle is too old for that JDK, upgrade your gradle or downgrade you JDK

Answer (score 1):

I noticed a subtlety in the way you download the IDE from jetbains.com

[image: screenshot of jetbrains.com]

You probably want JBR 8 and **not** JBR 11. Also, make sure your JDK is setup properly with jbsdk bintray downloader plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I recently upgraded my Ubantu to 18 from 16. After that I am facing this issue. Problem was during ubantu upgrade java is automatically upgraded to 11 from 8. Hence getting this error. You can simply downgrade jdk using [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1133216/downgrading-java-11-to-java-8) to solve this. Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Reintalling Intellij Worked for me.
You need to uninstall first before reinstall. While uninstalling, **ensure to select option to delete older cache and settings**

Answer (score 0):

check , maybe you have 2 times gradle in path

Answer (score -1):

**MODIFY default Boot JDK**

1. **OPEN** the Action Dialog

[image]

2. **SEARCH** : switch boot jdk

[image]

3. **SELECT** the JDK installed by you rather than the intellij default

[image]

4. **RESTART** intellij idea
5. **IGNORE** this popup at right-bottom on IDE
   [image]

*HOPE this solution is work for you .*

Comment: This works, but better to change the version for Gradle than changing Intellij Boot SDK. See below answer.